# Zopim / Zendesk Chat Integration with Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api, zendesk, zendesk-api, zopim

We have Zopim / Zendesk Chat on our website, and use Slack to communicate. I've been waiting for Zendesk to provide a public hook or a integration with Slack for year and they never seem to come out with anything.

Has anyone successfully been able to get Zendesk Chat messages in Slack and be able to respond to the user in Slack so everything can be managed inside of Slack?

Comment: https://www.zendesk.com/apps/support/slack/ that looks like there is support for Slack for Zendesk. Or are you looking for something different?

Comment: we're considering buildout out this integration as a part of our Zendesk Slack integration: https://www.bubbleiq.com/zendesk-slack-integration. what exactly would you want it to do? a new channel for each chat?